# Applet Java console : remove trace message size limit

Tags: java, debugging, logging, applet, thread-safety

```
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.
Trace message truncated for length over 10K
```

I am doing some thread state review of an applet with lots of threads. When I press 'v' in the console, it just shows off lots of boring stuff and then cuts the most interesting (locked up and stuck) thread stack just in the middle. Is there any way to avoid that? Setting trace level to 5 did not affect this behaviour.

**UPD** Versioning matters; so I have this problem with jre 1.6.0_20-b02.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Java? http://www.java.net/external?url=https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6850604

Comment: Hell no, Oracle delivered a fix in u18 and I saw couple of guys still yelling at Oracle while using u20.
And it's reproduced in u24.
I'd better write my own thread introspector/dumper which does what I need once per minute.